# Add form input to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot find the accept answer on here.

Currently I have a simple html form, that allows the user to enter text, in this case a user name.

```
        <form class="Find Friend">

        <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
        <input type="text" id="friendsearch" placeholder="Find Friend" class="input-field" required/> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login">Find</button> 
        </form>
```

I want to capture that name in a variable for later use. Do I simply use ?

var findFriend =  friendsearch;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the `var` updating on each user input, you can use.

http://jsfiddle.net/gRZ7g/

```
var friendName;

$('#friendsearch').on('keyup', function(e) {
   friendName = $(this).val();
});

$('.show-value').click(function(e) {
   alert(friendName); 
});
```

Comment: Have to use keyup instead of keypress or keydown since the var gets set before the input gets a value on those.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this:

```
var findFriend = $('#friendsearch').val();
```

You have to use the jQuery selector to select the element by its id.